# Update list of objects inside method Flutter / Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

The code reads a firebase database then add each read in a list of objects (SalesData class), chartdata.

The problem is when I update the list (chartdata) in the function readData() I can print it inside databaseReference.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {}, but when it out of this bracket it is always empty. I an wondering how I could use this list in the chart constructor "dataSource: "

P.S if I hot reload the chart builds fine!!

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

// próximo passo: colocar os valores lidos do firebase em uma lista que seja

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  List<SalesData> chartdata = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // here I try to update the list chartdata, in order to build the chart
    readData();

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Home'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Read Data'),
              onPressed: () {
                readData();
              },
            ),
            SfCartesianChart(
                primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(),
                series: <LineSeries<SalesData, double>>[
                  LineSeries<SalesData, double>(
                      // Bind data source
                      dataSource: chartdata,
                      xValueMapper: (SalesData sales, _) => sales.year,
                      yValueMapper: (SalesData sales, _) => sales.sales)
                ])
          ],
        ));
  }

  final databaseReference =
      FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("UID/Esp_32");

  void readData() {
    databaseReference.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> dados = snapshot.value;
      dados.forEach((key, value) {
        chartdata.add(SalesData(value['VoltageIn'], value['Sensor40']));
      });
    });
  }
}

class SalesData {
  SalesData(this.year, this.sales);
  final double year;
  final double sales;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove the method ***readData()*** at the beginning of the build method this could cause an infinite loop, you can call in the **initState** method.

So in your *readData* method you need to call setState to update the screen, like this:

```
void readData() {
databaseReference.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
  Map<dynamic, dynamic> dados = snapshot.value;
  dados.forEach((key, value) {
    chartdata.add(SalesData(value['VoltageIn'], value['Sensor40']));
  });
  setState((){});
});
}
```

But I think that you should study some architecture to improve your code, like MVVM.